# Compute Number of Bits Used Without Building Huffman Tree

Tags: python, encoding, compression, huffman-code, information-theory

Say, I have a list of integers `x = [102, 102, 102, 1, 0, -1, -2000, -3, 3, 102, 1, 0, -1, -1, -2000, -2000, -2000, -2000, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 3]` and the frequencies for each number is:

```
Integer  Count
    102      4
      3      2
      1      3
      0      4
     -1      5
     -3      1
  -2000      5
```

If I generate a Huffman tree and then encode this sequence, I find that the total number of bits necessary for encoding this list is 65 bits. In theory, the order of the integers shouldn't matter (i.e., I can shuffle this list of integers) as it should still produce the same number of bits (65).

Considering that I only want to compute the number of bits and I don't care about the actual encoding or the tree, is there a faster/better way to compute  the number of bits used (i.e., 65) without having to explicitly construct the Huffman tree? Perhaps, it may be possible to generate the bit count based on the frequency count alone?

Comment: Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

Applying Huffman's algorithm is the only way to find the code lengths. You do not need to make an explicit tree to do that though, and you do not need to generate the actual codes. See https://github.com/madler/brotli/blob/master/huff.c .